# How to pop/remove the next item (any) in a key-value-pair table in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

In Lua how would one pop/remove the next item (any order) in a key-value-pair table?

Is this possible without having to iterate using `pairs`?

Comment: Are the key's index based or associative based?

Comment: associative I think - i.e. "this"=23, "that"=234 etc

Comment: What *next* item? Can you give an example of what you'r trying to do?  Anyway, to remove a table entry, just do `t[k]=nil`, where `t` contains the table and `k` contains the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a primitive function `next`, you can call `next(t,k)`, where `k` is a key of the table `t`, returns a next key in the table, in an arbitrary order, and the value associated with this key.

If `k` is `nil`, `next(t,k)` returns the first element if there is one. So you can iterate the table from calling `next(t,nil)` and end when the next key is `nil`.

This is an simple example to demonstrate the use of `next`:

```
local t = {a = "va", b = "vb", c = "vc"}

local k,v = next(t,nil)
print(k,v)
k,v = next(t,k)
print(k,v)
k,v = next(t,k)
print(k,v)
k,v = next(t,k)
print(k,v)
```

Output:

```
a       va
c       vc
b       vb
nil     nil
```

Answer (score 1):

The global function [next](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-next) is useful here. The docs explain it pretty well in general. To use it iteratively, this is 'key':

> You may ... modify existing fields. In particular, you may clear
>   existing fields.

A simple pop function:

```
 -- removes and returns an arbitrary key-value pair from a table, otherwise nil
 local pop = function (t)
    local key, value = next(t)
    if key ~= nil then
        t[key] = nil
    end
    return key, value
end
```

Demo:

```
local test = { "one", c = "see", "two", a = "ayy", b = "bee", "three" }
assert(next(test), "Table was expected to be non-empty")

local key, value = pop(test)
while key do
   print(key, value)
   key, value = pop(test)
end

assert(not next(test), "Table was expected to be empty")
```

If you run the demo multiple times, you might see the arbitrariness of the table sequence.